# ArgumentOutOfRangeException with data-binding when debugger is running [VS2010]

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, data-binding, datetimepicker

### Problem

Suppose that you are having a class that you want to perform data-binding on. It looks like that:

```
public class DataClass
{
    private DateTime date;

    public DataClass()
    {
        date = new DateTime(2014, 1, 1);
    }

    public DateTime Date
    {
        get { return date; }
        set { date = value; }
    }

}
```

Now suppose that you have a form and that you want to bind an instance of DataClass on a DateTimePicker in that form. You create and initialize the databinding like this (Designer code):

```
bindingSource = new System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource(this.components);
bindingSource.DataSource = typeof(DataBindTest.DataClass)
```

Then you (inevitably) bind to the date picker (Designer code):

```
dateTimePicker.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Value", this.bindingSource, "Date", true));
```

and set the desired object to the data source:

```
bindingSource.DataSource = new DataClass();
```

When you try to **debug** your app, you get that Exception:

> ArgumentOutOfRangeException Value of '1/1/0001 00:00:00' is not valid for 'Value'. 'Value' should be between 'MinDate' and 'MaxDate'.

Funny thing though, when you try to **run** (i.e. no debugger) the app, everything is fine.

### Attempted Solutions

I tried to set the Data Source Update Mode to "Never", I tried to set Format Type to "Date Time", I tried to set Null Value to something like "01/01/2000" (without quotes) and guess what, nothing significant happened.

Now there are some solutions eg

- don't use data binding or
- subclass the date picker and "override" Value so that it's not punishing you for giving it such a low value or (even better)
- find out why the heck the binding process passes an unused value to the binded control while the desired value is right there, in the object.

That's true for every range checking control such as NumericUpDowns. So I am looking for an answer (and hopefully a solution) for the last question. I can't believe that somebody, while implementing the binding process, had the idea to pass default values in the properties and did not predict for the case of range checking controls.

**Edit**
One more important thing: The problem is **not** reproducible on .net framework 3.5 it's on 4.0 that I use.

Comment: This code must works without problem.

Answer (score 1):

I found that I had the same problem while binding the Value property of the DateTimePicker (in .Net 4.5).

The problems disappeared when binding the same DateTime struct to the Text property of the picker.

It is a bit counter-intuitive, but it works fine both ways (displaying an existing value and storing a selected date to the struct.

It still throws a First chance exception of type 'system.argumentoutofrangeexception', but that is caught by the dll where the same exception is not caught when binding to the Value property.

Hope that helps someone.

With regards,
Leo Prast